# CORS issue asp.net core web api. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: asp.net-core, post, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using **asp net core 2.1** and I have an account controller with following methods:

```
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<object> Login([FromBody] IdentityUserForLoginDto userForLogin)
    {...}
    [HttpPost("register")]
    public async Task<object> Register([FromBody] IdentityClientForRegistrationDto userForRegistration)
    {...}
```

When I fetch data on login method, everything works fine and user normally logs in, but when I try to register new user I get CORS issue:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:53531/api/account/register' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

and:

> POST http://localhost:53531/api/account/register net::ERR_FAILED

In my backend I tried every possible combination of enabling CORS and for now I have this:

*ConfigureServices:*

```
        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("ApiCorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3001")
                .AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        }));
```

*Configure*

```
app.UseCors("ApiCorsPolicy");
```

Client-side data fetching:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:53531/api/account/register`, {          
        method: 'POST',        
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},   

        body: JSON.stringify(values)


            })
    .then(handleResponse)
    .then(user => {

        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        currentUserSubject.next(user);

        return user;
    });
```

Both of them are placed **before** Add/UseMvc.
I've tried with AllowAnyOrigin, [EnableCors] etc..but always the same.
I want to point out that I've also tried with disabling cors from client but in that case I get text/plain media type and I explicitly want **application/json**.

Also, when I make the same request in postman everything works great..

Does anyone have any idea how to fix that issue?

Comment: Can you share the client side code for calling the register endpoint?

Comment: I've edited original post and added that part

Comment: I noticed you are using `fetch` for making API call. https://github.com/github/fetch can you try adding `credentials: 'include'` in options as mentioned here https://github.github.io/fetch/

Comment: I did, still the same.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. Problem was in data that was sent to server..it wasn't in format that server expected it to be